# Javascript Object scope

Tags: javascript

This is a simplification of something that I've come up against in a larger project so I hope it makes sense.

I have two Objects:

```
FirstObj = {
    data : [],

    init : function()
    {
        for(var a = 0; a < 20; a++)
        {
            this.data[a] = 1;
        }
    }
};


SecondObj = {
    init : function()
    {
        var cell = FirstObj.data[0];
        cell = 0;
    }   
};
```

I then call the two `init` methods and log the results:

```
(function(){
    FirstObj.init();
    SecondObj.init();
    console.log(FirstObj.data);
})()
```

Now, I was assuming - based on my basis in Actionscript - that the log would show an `Array` in which the first item is a `0` and the rest all `1` but the `0` does not seem to stick.

Why does the assignment of the `0` value not succeed here and yet works fine if, instead of `cell = 0` I target directly at `FirstObj.data[0] = 0`.

I'm guessing this is a scope thing and I can work round it but I'm trying to get a proper understanding of how JS actually handles this stuff, especially when lumping code into Objects like this (as an aside, is this a good approach in peoples general opinion?).

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers in JavaScript are something called [primitive value types](http://es5.github.io/#x8) (alongside strings, booleans `null` and `undefined`).

This means, that when you do

```
var cell = FirstObj.data[0];
```

You're passing the *value* in `FirstObj.data[0]` and not a refernece to it.

What you're doing is like:

```
var x = 5;
var y = x; // y is now 5 
y = 4; // y is 4, x is still 5.
```

Of course, something like `FirstObj.data[0] = 0` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Array indexing returns values in Javascript, not references. It means that once `data[0]` is assigned to `cell`, further modification of `cell` will not affect `data[0]`.

Assigning the array itself would result in the behavior you're looking for:

```
SecondObj = {
    init : function()
    {
        var cells = FirstObj.data;
        cells[0] = 0;  // Will also affect data[0].
    }   
};
```